# Remove gcc from Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, uninstall, gcc, software-uninstall

I want to completely remove `gcc` from Ubuntu. I am using `gcc 4.9` which happens to be the latest version.

How can I remove it completely from my system?

Comment: Can I ask you _why_ ? You will need it eventually

Comment: Probably trying to get nvidia drivers to work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is one thing (thank you @kos):

> I definitely wouldn't remove `gcc` in general, but if I had to I
>   wouldn't do it this way: this will remove also `build-essential`
>   and hence `make`; for one, if you have the nVidia > drivers installed it will remove those as well, since they
>   depend on `make`, plus who knows what other stuff.

With other words, know what you do. **;-)**

---

If you only need a reinstall, use

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc-4.9
```

---

If you *really, really* need to remove `gcc-4.9`, use this short and **dangerous command:**

```
sudo apt-get purge gcc-4.9
```

Comment: I just wanted to remove it and install it all over again. If I install it again will it be a problem still?

Comment: yes. Use `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc-4.9` instead

Comment: What makes it dangerous?

Answer (score 5):

use below command , --purge remove option is equivalent to purge

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove gcc-4.9
```

according `apt-get` manual:

```
--purge
   Use purge instead of remove for anything that would be removed. An
   asterisk ("*") will be displayed next to packages which are
   scheduled to be purged.  remove --purge is equivalent to the purge
   command. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Purge.
```

Comment: equivalents are always good =)